# Slow SELECT with LEFT JOIN over 4 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

My database has 4 tables: org_addresses, org_main, zipcodes and cities.

The table **org_addresses** contains address data for organizations, the table **org_main** contains the main data for these organizations, the table **zipcodes** contains city zipcodes, and the table **cities** contains city names.

org_addresses:

```
| id | org_id | address_line | zipcode |
```

org_main:

```
| id | name |
```

zipcodes

```
| id | city_id | zipcode |
```

cities

```
| id | name |
```

In my query, I join all 4 tables using LEFT JOIN together to output complete data as a list with 1600 organizations.

As soon as I join the table zipcodes via LEFT JOIN and then join to the table cities, the request slows down to 4 seconds. Without the table zipcodes, the query takes 0.009 seconds.

```
SELECT a.org_id
     , a.address_line2
     , a.zipcode
     , m.name
  FROM org_addresses a
  LEFT 
  JOIN org_main m
    ON a.org_id = m.id
  LEFT 
  JOIN zipcodes z
    ON a.zipcode = z.zipcode
  LEFT 
  JOIN cities c
    ON z.city_id = c.id
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are outer joining tables from which you select no columns. This is pointless

Comment: `m.short_description` does not exist in your data model

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the execution plans of the queries to see what is happening.

My guess would be that `zipcodes(zipcode)` is not indexed (and probably not `cities(city)`.  It is curious that you are not joining on the tables `id` instead.

Comment: To clarify, Gordon is referring to `EXPLAIN`.  This causes MySQL to analyze your query and to output the so-called "execution plan," which is the thing that actually drives the query engine. *(The first thing that happens when running any query is to develop the execution plan.)*  Compare the different `EXPLAIN` results to see why MySQL is suddenly being forced to take the slow boat.

Comment: Execution plans are based not only on the SQL text but also things like the presence or absence of indexes, and statistics that are maintained by the system concerning the data itself.  An identical SQL string might produce two entirely different execution plans depending on "circumstances that prevail at this moment."  The absence of proper indexes is a likely culprit, but a slowdown from 0.09 sec to +4 sec *is* quite extraordinary.

Comment: I'd think a sql query needs to run before you can look at the plan.  I doubt this even executes.

Answer (score 0):

be sure you have proper index

on table  org_addresses composite index on columns  (org_id, zipcode)

on table  zipcodes column composite index on columns ( city_id, zipcode)

on table  cities on column (id)